# How to get error position using the spirit parser

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

I wrote a simple parser with spirit, akin to json (but simpler and more specialised). By following the advice in [here](http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/qi-example/tracking-the-input-position-while-parsing/), I tried to implement error handling by tracking the error position. In particular, my parsing function is as follows

```
bool parse_properties(std::istream& is, const std::string &filename, PropertyList &pset)
{
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
    namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
    namespace classic = boost::spirit::classic;

    typedef std::istreambuf_iterator<char> base_iterator_type;
    base_iterator_type in_begin(is);

    // convert input iterator to forward iterator, usable by spirit parser
    typedef boost::spirit::multi_pass<base_iterator_type> forward_iterator_type;
    forward_iterator_type fwd_begin = boost::spirit::make_default_multi_pass(in_begin);
    forward_iterator_type fwd_end;

    // wrap forward iterator with position iterator, to record the position
    typedef classic::position_iterator2<forward_iterator_type> pos_iterator_type;
    pos_iterator_type position_begin(fwd_begin, fwd_end, filename);
    pos_iterator_type position_end;

    qi::rule<pos_iterator_type> skipper = ascii::space | 
    '#' >> *(ascii::char_ - qi::eol) >> qi::eol; 

    property_set_grammar<pos_iterator_type, qi::rule<pos_iterator_type> > g;
    bool r = false;
    try {
        r = phrase_parse(position_begin, 
                         position_end, 
             g, skipper, pset);
    }
    catch(const qi::expectation_failure<pos_iterator_type>& e) {
        const classic::file_position_base<std::string>& pos = e.first.get_position();
        std::stringstream msg;
        msg <<
            "parse error at file " << pos.file <<
            " line " << pos.line << " column " << pos.column << std::endl <<
            "'" << e.first.get_currentline() << "'" << std::endl <<
            std::setw(pos.column) << " " << "^- here";
        throw std::runtime_error(msg.str());
    }

    return r;
}
```

Unfortunately, it does not work. Function `phrase_parse` always returns false immediately, both for correct and for incorrect files, and never raises any exception.

However, when I modify the above code to use a simple `forward_iterator` instead of the `classic::position_iterator2` it works fine, but of course it does not track the error position. The very strange thing is that the original example in [here](http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/qi-example/tracking-the-input-position-while-parsing/) works fine. So maybe the problem is related to my grammar. Here it follows:

```
template <typename Iterator, typename Skipper>
struct property_set_grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, PropertyList(),
                                          Skipper>
{
    qi::rule<Iterator, Property(), Skipper> prop;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), Skipper> name;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), Skipper> type;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), Skipper> value;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), Skipper> value_simple;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), Skipper> value_quoted;
    qi::rule<Iterator, PropertyList(), Skipper> plist;

    property_set_grammar() : 
        property_set_grammar::base_type(plist, "Set of Properties") {
        using qi::lit;
        using qi::alpha;
        using qi::alnum;
        using qi::lexeme;
        using qi::char_;

        name = lexeme[alpha >> *alnum];
        type = lexeme[alpha >> *alnum];
        value_simple = lexeme[*(alnum - lit('"'))];
        value_quoted = lit('"') > lexeme[*(char_ - lit('"'))] > lit('"');
        value = (value_quoted | value_simple);

        prop = name >> '=' > value > ';';
        plist = type >> '(' > name > ')' > '{' >> *(prop | plist) > '}' > ';';
    }
};
```

I am using g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2 and version 1.50 of the boost libraries.

Is there anything stupid that I am overlooking? If needed, I can provide the complete code (it's just a few files).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that boost::spirit::position_iterator is bugged.

You can edit the headers of `position_iterator` as suggested in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005273/strange-error-with-boostspiritposition-iterator2).

Or you can implement your own position_iterator, I did this by basically copy-and-paste  the original code of `boost::spirit::position_iterator`, then remove some unneeded stuff.

<del>Also, when parsing from `istream`, make sure to set the `noskipws` manip:</del>

```
//is >> std::noskipws;
```

**EDIT:** Not needed with istreambuf_iterator

Comment: Thanks a lot! I hope someone will fix the bug soon.